# Need to get list of records grouped by foreign key in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I have 2 tables interestTypes and interests table in a way that interest record have interestTypeId reference stored.

Now I need list of interestTypes with their interests.

```
const interestSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 50,
      required: true
    },
    interestTypes: [
      {
        interestTypeId: {
          type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
          ref: 'interestType'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)

const interestTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 50,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)
```

I know this can be done with lookup aggregation but I messed it up. This code is written in interests model

```
interestSchema.statics.getTypes = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    this.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup":
          {
            "from": "interestTypes",
            "localField": "interestType",
            "as": "interestTypes",
            "foreignField": "_id",
          }
      },
      {
        "$group": 
          {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "interestTypes": { "$push": "$interestTypes" }
          }
        }
    ],
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) return reject(err)        
        resolve(result)
      }
    )
}
```

Not able to get desired result

What I want this method to return is something like this

```
[
{
    id: interestTypeIdRef1,
    name: interestType1
    interests: [
    {
        id: interestIdRef1,
        name: interestType1
    },
    {
        id: interestIdRef2,
        name: interestType2
    },
    {
        id: interestIdRef3,
        name: interestType3
    }
    ]
},
{
    id: interestTypeIdRef2,
    name: interestType1
    interests: [
    {
        id: interestIdRef2,
        name: interestType1
    },
    {
        id: interestIdRef3,
        name: interestType2
    },
    {
        id: interestIdRef4,
        name: interestType3
    }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use below link to check the query.
This is query which is doing the lookups in aggregation

sample database created

```
db={
  "interestTypes": [
    {
      "typeId": 1,
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "typeId": 2,
      "type": "type2"
    }
  ],
  "interests": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "interestName": "interest1",
      "interestTypeId": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "interestName": "interest2",
      "interestTypeId": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "interestName": "interest3",
      "interestTypeId": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "interestName": "interest4",
      "interestTypeId": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "interestName": "interest5",
      "interestTypeId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

sample answer

```
db.interestTypes.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "interests",
      localField: "typeId",
      foreignField: "interestTypeId",
      as: "interesetTypesWithInterest"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      type: 1,
      interestTypeId: "$typeId",
      interests: "$interesetTypesWithInterest"
    }
  }
])
```

use this link for verification
https://mongoplayground.net/p/3f5AzKQMamw Since you are familiar to convert the mongodb code to Mongoose it will help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23920655)

Comment: agree with your suggestion.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru this should not mean you downvote the answer. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted your answer. I simply ran into it in the review queue and took the appropriate action. Do not assume I downvoted because the automatically-generated comment came from me.

Comment: no worries, @MihaiChelaru Thanks for your suggestion. This will help me to post more explanatory answers in future.

Comment: Thanks @Sachin I was able to resolve my problem with your approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

start Your Aggregation from interestTypeSchema for your desired Output.

```
InterestSchema.statics.getTypes = function () {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    interestType.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'interestSchema',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'interestTypeId',
                as: 'interests'
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                name:1,
                interests:1,
            }
        }
    ],
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            resolve(result)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't give me interests array.

[{ id: interestTypeIdRef1, name: interestType1 },{ id: interestTypeIdRef2, name: interestType1 }]

Comment: Thanks @vishal But now it is giving empty list [{ id: interestTypeIdRef1, name: interestType1, interests: [] },{ id: interestTypeIdRef2, name: interestType1, interests: [] }]